# Server 2008/2012 (R2) group policy scheduled task not applying

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I am at wit's end and totally confused. The goal is to take group policies(one per day of a week) and set a scheduled task which will trigger a reboot on that day at a specific time.

So I made them (see example below) yet.....they don't work? I've done additional manual reboots of the servers, `gpupdate /force` on the servers, changed the GPO from 'create' to 'update', and nothing seems to make them actually get applied.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My two questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong? I just want to schedule graceful restarts on a recurring pattern through group policy (other options are welcome, I guess)
2. How can I fix it or acheive the same end result?

Goal is simply to: Set policyGPO from AD to reboot servers on certain days, push scheduled tasks to each server the GPO is attached to, have the servers run their received scheduled task going forward.

Edit - gpresult /H 
[image]

Comment: The GPO is edited on what OS ? On 2012R2 you got more scheduled task's option, thus it can't apply it to the 2008R2. I would use the GPO's console on a 2008R2 to push it on 2008R2's server in example

Comment: @yagmoth555 I have the RSAT tools on a Windows 8.1 client, forest functional level of domain is 2008 R2. Does it make a difference if I create the Group policy from the RSAT tools vs. on a domain controller? I wasn't aware that it did. Unless you are referring to which server I am connected to with the GPO tools in RSAT?

Comment: Yes, it make a difference, maybe not the why of your bug, but it make a diff.

Comment: If you've one GPO per day of the week, I guess you're filtering and applying them by groups... Have you checked your security groups, or your WMI filter? What's the output of gpresult/rsop.msc?

Comment: Just to clarify, are the tasks not being created, or are they just not running? Group policy scheduled tasks doesn't actually have anything to do with running the tasks, it just automates creating the task objects on the target systems.

Comment: Sorry for the major delay @tfrederick74656 and yagmoth555. The tasks are not visible on the system after I connect to them. I assumed the schedule would have started the running of them as well. Advice/guides I should follow? Goal is simply to: Set policy from AD to reboot servers on certain days, push scheduled tasks to each server the GPO is attached to, have servers running their received scheduled task.

Comment: Does `gpresult /h` show the policy?

Comment: @GregAskew Yes, image attached above incase a config is wrong.

Comment: Did you created a new GPO logged from a 2008R2 directly, or RSAT from a Windows 7, as like I told, if option for WS2012R2 got pushed, the computer will not add that task into a 2008R2

Comment: @yagmoth555 you're absolutely right. I created the policies on a 2008 R2 server and it does appear to have applied to those. I connected to a 2012 R2 controller with GPO Mgmt tools and I see those policies but the 2012R2 servers which should be receiving the policy are not adding the task. Do I need to create 2 instances of the task? One from 2012, one from 2008?

Comment: Yes, and you can create a wmi filter on the gpo to target the correct OS version too (select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where Version like "6.1%" and ProductType = "3" (for 2008r2) and use "6.2%" for 2012r2) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheduled task must be created in the GPO's console while sitting in the same OS core version that you will target. In example for 2008R2 you need to edit with a 2008R2 server or to use the RSAT tool on a Windows 7.

At each new OS version they add new scheduled task settings, and thus the task become not valid if the GPO target a OS that does not know those settings. (and thus does not apply)

If you have a mixed OU for your server you can use a WMI filter to target the correct OS with your GPO, like;

For Windows 2008R2 server

```
select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where Version like "6.1%" and ProductType = "2"
```

For Windows 2012R2

```
select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where Version like "6.2%" and ProductType = "2"
```

Comment: Thanks man! Really appreciate your help and this hit the mark perfectly! Out of curiosity - is there a better recommended way to schedule server reboots you would recommend?

Comment: @Abraxas Glad it helped :) For the script its the best way! as I tried some monitoring tool in the past, and when I was scheduling a reboot in the tool in the background it added a planned task.. So I think in the end a planned shutdown like you do is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this function anymore:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2962486.

You need either create the tasks manual or use PowerShell or a like to script the creation of the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I have also recently run into an issue with creating scheduled tasks via group policy on my server 2012 R2 domain.Windows 2008 R2 is normal. I have fixed it.

Below is the solution(need to note the two points).Just for reference.

Point 1:create a task select Schedule Task(At least windows 7)or Immediate Task(At least windows 7).The normal task (Schedule Task does't work for 2012 R2)

[image]

Point 2:select user "NT AUTHORITY\System" to run the task.

[image]